# How to send an email from pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is it possible to send a mail from JavaScript?

Important note: My JavaScript is a MongoDB script, so it is **not inside a browser/web page**

My MongoDB server has no access to the internet, just the `mailhost` mail server.
Thus standard solution like `window.open('mailto:test@example.com')` or [SmtpJS.com](https://smtpjs.com/) are not possible.

Mongo shell is able to call system binary, e.g.

```
run("sh", "-c", `echo "The message body" | mail -s "The Subject" recip@emailsite.com`);
```

But as far as I know, the `run` command is/was for internal purpose only and it might be removed already in current release.

Comment: why dont you create another service that sends mail and access it over HTTPS?  thats what javascript does best...making rest calls

Comment: No, *plain* JavaScript cannot do that since there are no APIs for network access. However that's not what you're actually asking. The mongodb JavaScript environment (I assume you refer to [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/)?) *does* provide a networking API though, and yes you can use it to send emails to your mailhost.

Comment: @Bergi, I am still using the legacy [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/). Do you have any reference to the networking API? I don't find any, neither for `mongo` nor for `mongosh`.

Comment: @Ctznkane525, as mentioned I am not in a browser environment. Commands like `request = new XMLHttpRequest()` or `response = await fetch('http://localhost/mail-service.json')` return an error `uncaught exception: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Doesn't [the documentation on `require`ing nodejs modules](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/#use-require---to-include-external-files-and-modules) apply to the old mongo shell as well?

Comment: `require` and other many API's are not available in legacy shell, new `mongosh` looks better. However, basic methods like `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch` are not available. How can I get them if they are not supported natively?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Those "basic methods" you mention are browser apis, and they won't help you to send email anyway. What you need is a [bare network socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), or better yet just the [mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail) or [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) package.

Comment: @Bergi, Yes, for this I was looking. The "new" mongosh is still awful and has many bugs - let's see how it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile the new `mongosh` became much better. In version 1.1.9 or newer I did not find any obvious bugs anymore. So you can use standard npm packages like `nodemailer`